# Use of も particle when stating what someone said

Tags: grammar, particle-も

I believe the following sentence...

メアリーさんも来ると言っていましたから。

...translates as "Because Mary said that she would come."

Can you tell me what the function of the も particle is in this instance? I'm wondering if it's intended to be used to emphasise Mary somehow.

To clarify, person A said

> Shall we start eating?

to which person B said

> Not yet. メアリーさんも来ると言っていましたから。

The translation that makes the most sense to me would be

> Because Mary said that she would come as well

but that's not the given translation, so I wondered if も was being used in another way.

Comment: Without more context, we do not even know what the 「も」 even modifies.  Mary said that she, too, would come?  An unmentioned someone said that Mary, too, would come?  Mary, too, said that an unmentioned someone  would come?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to make clarifications, not the comments. Also, in general, it’s good to provide all the original text along with the translations.

Answer (score -1):

In this context, メアリーさんも corresponds to 'Mary also'.